# i want to show marker on google map by getting longitude and latitude from json

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to show marker on google map by getting longitude and latitude from json..if i use marker in AsyncTask it is not showing marker at given latlng...
i am here so far...thanks in advance....

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
String city = "New Delhi";
String location = null;
double lat;
double lng ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    new JSONTask().execute("http://www.xxxxxxx.com/bar/mob.php");
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-30, 140);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // i want use that lat and lng here which i am getting in AsyncTask
    LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Bardata>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Bardata> doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("location", location)
                    .appendQueryParameter("city", city);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();


            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            System.out.println("Returned value " + finalJson.toString());

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("home");

            List<Bardata> bardataList = new ArrayList<>();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {


                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Bardata barData = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), Bardata.class);
                bardataList.add(barData);


                lat = barData.getLatitude();
                lng = barData.getLongitude();

               /* LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("Marker"));
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);*/



            }
            return bardataList;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<Bardata> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Currently,we are not present in your city", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}}
```

bardata.java

```
public class Bardata {


private String barname;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}


public String getBarname() {
    return barname;
}

public void setBarname(String barname) {
    this.barname = barname;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this question there is example code given on github
try [this](https://gist.github.com/saxman/5347195)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the markers on the UI thread, so you will need to call the method to add markers from within runOnUiThread

```
for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {


 JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
 Bardata barData = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), Bardata.class);
 bardataList.add(barData);


 lat = barData.getLatitude();
 lng = barData.getLongitude();
 LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   try {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

   } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error adding marker", e);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: The logcat has no errors or warnings, but the markers aren't showing up.

Comment: Are the markers that are being added in the same location where your map is getting initialized?  In the onMapReady method you are moving the map to Sydney.